# MAMP & localhost Wordpress install Error connecting to the database.

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I use Mamp daily for local Wordpress Installs. For no apparent reason, it has suddenly stopped the install process. 
Now when i download a fresh copy of WP and fire it up, I just get the "error establishing a database connection" message instead of the fresh install screen.

Note this is a brand new install, no wp-config or pre existing install data.

does anyone know what could suddenly cause this issue?

Comment: Did you check your `vhost` declaration in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf` ?

Comment: No I haven't. What would I be looking for in that file?